# TCP/IP: can i REMOTELY (via VPN) access mis-addressed device on remote LAN?

Tags: networking, vpn, tcpip

i sent a pre-configured box to client to drop onto their LAN.  while i was sure i left it as DHCP, when i connect to the LAN through the VPN i'm not seeing it pull an address from the router and it isn't showing up on the ARP tables.  sooo... maybe i left it as a static IP... for the wrong subnet.  so my question is how can i connect to this device?  if it is still on static, i know the IP, et al.  but i'm not sure, given that i'm connecting via VPN, how to access this device to properly correct it's IP.  were it on the same LAN, no problem, but now its on a remote LAN and the VPN complicates this.

while this *sounds* like [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/504254/tcp-ip-routing-accessing-a-lan-device-with-wrong-static-ip-configuration), the key difference is that i am connecting to the remote LAN via VPN.  if it was on my local LAN, this would be a non-issue.

anyway.  i'd appreciate some guidance here so i don't have to either fly out to client's site or play FedEx shuffle...

Comment: Can you modify the VPN and remote router parameters ?

Comment: technically, yes.  but the VPN is constantly in use by the staff... although i could do it after hours...  what are you thinking?

Answer (score 2):

Another possible way:

1. Connect to another computer on the remote network while you're connected to the VPN.
2. Add an ip address/subnet mask in the same subnet as your device to the other computer as an additional ip address.
3. Connect to your device from the other computer.
4. Fix your device.
5. Remove the additional ip address from the other computer.

Comment: this was very useful.  didn't work for this case because i didn't remember the IP correctly, but it came in handy for another similar situation.  thank you.  :)

Answer (score 1):

One possible way:

1. Add the static subnet to the remote router as a secondary address.
2. Modify the VPN domain to include the static subnet.
3. Add any additional routing as necessary.

Comment: never thought of adding a secondary address!  thank you.